# react-leaflet basic example rendering

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v4

I'm using leaflet and react-leaflet for the first time and using their basic example [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/leaflet-test-nsthkl?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq0jalex00063b6posy39tad%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq0jalex00023b6pck8zgkpd%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq0jalex00033b6pduomg31h%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq0jalex00053b6p2cd5aws6%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq0jalex00023b6pck8zgkpd%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq0jalex00023b6pck8zgkpd%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clq0jalex00053b6p2cd5aws6%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq0jalex00043b6pgdjsf9fz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq0jalex00053b6p2cd5aws6%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq0jalex00043b6pgdjsf9fz%2522%257D%252C%2522clq0jalex00033b6pduomg31h%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq0jalex00033b6pduomg31h%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

and the map is broken in multiple sections with half not visible.

```
<MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
```

The versions used are
leaflet : 1.9.4
react-leaflet : 4.2.1
react : 18.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You juste need to import leaflet CSS file and set the height and width of the **MapContainer**, the class name is **leaflet-container**

```
// Component file
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"

// CSS file
.leaflet-container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

don't forget to install leaflet package

```
npm install leaflet
```